# Refresh token before Unauthorized Redirect in React and NodeJS

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

Is there any example of a token refresh flow using Apollo? I have a site that redirects users who dont have a token and need to refresh before they are redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the docs of the package `apollo-link-error`.

```
onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      for (let err of graphQLErrors) {
        switch (err.extensions.code) {
          case 'UNAUTHENTICATED':
            // error code is set to UNAUTHENTICATED
            // when AuthenticationError thrown in resolver

            // modify the operation context with a new token
            const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
            operation.setContext({
              headers: {
                ...oldHeaders,
                authorization: getNewToken(),
              },
            });
            // retry the request, returning the new observable
            return forward(operation);
        }
      }
    }
    if (networkError) {
      console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
      // if you would also like to retry automatically on
      // network errors, we recommend that you use
      // apollo-link-retry
    }
  }
);
```